# Binary Prime-Chunks

Tags: code-golf, sequence, binary

## We are searching for a sequence

Take the **natural numbers**
`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14...`

Convert to **base-2**
`1,10,11,100,101,110,111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110...`

**Concatenate** the above numbers
`110111001011101111000100110101011110011011110...`

**Partition** this number in **Prime-Chunks**
(chunks containing a prime number of digits)
Primes are taken in asceding  order `2,3,5,7,11,13,17...`

`[11][011][10010][1110111][10001001101][0101111001101][1110...]`

and find the **Sum of the digits of each chunk**

`Primes        2   3     5       7          11            13        17`     
`Chunks      [11][011][10010][1110111][10001001101][0101111001101][1110...]`
`SumOfDigits   2   2     2       6          5             8`

## The Sequence

> 2, 2, 2, 6, 5, 8, 9, 10, 14, 22, 11, 18, 25, 27, 32, 21, 28, 32, 40, 40, 49, 49, 32, 41, 49, 53, 63, 55, 63, 70, 87, 73, 51, 63, 71, 78, 78, 90, 107, 86, 96, 108, 115, 128, 138, 92, 83, 95, 102, 110, 130, 106, 122, 141, 149, 163, 130, 140, 151, 165, 181, 165, 204, 200, 234, 100, 130, 138, 167, 149, 169, 180, 209, 166, 189, 194, 222, 205, 234, 260, 216, 206, 217, 241, 240, 267, 289, 242, 274, 308, 286, 329, 338, 155, 189, 225, 197, 240, 272, 217, 254, 282, 287, 317, 281, 256, 299, 286, 331, 337, 316, 350, 354, 391, 367, 282, 327, 313, 364, 358, 348, 397, 406, 466...

## The Challenge

Find the `nth` term of the above sequence

## Input

An integer `n>0`

## Test Cases

```
1->2   
3->2    
6->8    
36->78 
60->165    
160->581     
260->1099    
350->1345
```

This is [codegolf](/questions/tagged/codegolf).Shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/145421/the-binary-square-diagonal-sequence) (first three steps are the same)

Comment: Downvoted because this feels too much like a bunch of challenges mashed together.

Answer (score 14):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 8 bytes

```
Σ!CİpṁḋN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9xiRecjGwoe7mx8uKPb7////4YGAA)

### Explanation

```
Σ!CİpṁḋN
       N   Start with the infinite list of natural numbers.
     ṁḋ    Convert each to its binary representation and join them all together. (A)
   İp      Get the infinite list of primes. (B)
  C        Split (A) into chunks of lengths (B).
 !         Retrieve the nth chunk (where n is the input).
Σ          Sum the bits in this chunk.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
RÆNµSRBFṁRṪS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9qZWxsef//UsOGTsK1U1JCRuG5gVLhuapT/8W8w4figqxH//9bKnJhbmdlKDEsIDM3KSwgNjBd)

#### How it works

```
RÆNµSRBFṁRṪS  Main link. Argument: n

R             Range; yield [1, ..., n].
 ÆN           N-th prime; yield P := [p(1), ..., p(n)].
   µ          Begin a new, monadic chain with argument P.
    S         Take the sum of P, yielding s := p(1) + ... + p(n).
     R        Range; yield [1, ..., s].
      B       Binary; convert all integers from 1 to s to base 2.
       F      Flatten the resulting array.
         R    Range; yield [[1, ..., p(1)], ..., [1, ..., p(n)]].
        ṁ     Mold; reshape the result to the left like the result to the right.
          Ṫ   Tail; take the last chunk.
           S  Take the sum, counting the set digits.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

#### Code

Can get pretty slow for large numbers:

```
ÅpDOLbJs£`SO
```

Uses the **05AB1E**-encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cGuBi79PklfxocUJwf7//xubGgAA)

#### Explanation

```
Åp              # Get a list of the first <input> primes
  DO            # Duplicate and sum the primes
    L           # Create the list [1, .., <sum>]
     bJ         # Convert to binary and join into a single string
       s£       # Get the slices [a[0:2], a[2:2+3], a[2+3:2+3+5], a[2+3+5:2+3+5+7], ...] 
                  corresponding to the list of primes
         `SO    # Get the last one and sum up it's digits
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 71 bytes

```
(Tr/@TakeList[Join@@IntegerDigits[Range[#^2+1],2],Prime~Array~#])[[#]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/BfI6RI3yEkMTvVJ7O4JNorPzPPwcEzryQ1PbXIJTM9s6Q4OigxLz01WjnOSNswVscoViegKDM3tc6xqCixsk45VjM6Wjk2Vu0/UDSvRMEhLdrY1CD2PwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
RÆNSRBF
RÆN+\‘ṬœṗÇ⁸ịS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/ocJtfcJCTGxeIoR3zqGHGw51rjk5@uHP64fZHjTse7u4O/v//v5kBAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>206</s> 200 bytes

```r
function(n){a=p=j=y=2
for(i in 2:n-1){while(sum(y)<4*a){x=as.double(rev(intToBits(j)))
y=c(y,x[cumsum(x)>0])
j=j+1}
b=1:a
y=y[-b]
z=outer(k<-b+a,p,'%%')
p=c(a<-k[!apply(z<1,1,sum)][1],p)}
sum(y[1:a])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY/BboMwEETv/gqKFGW3WSqcVBwQ7qHf0BvlYFxQTRJjgWlxEN9OTa@jmac3w9aKrZ2Mcro3YHCRwopOeHFmbT@AjrSJzrlJOC6/3/rWwDjdwWPx@ixxmYUcX776qQ750PyANu6jf9duhA4RmRcKPM2lmu77asa3tELWie7EV1YLnstQ8WVSV@wh@sk1A1yLpD5JsnQ8HI7IbCDIIrmWT9Lam4dHwYlTgGFV8oosruzfpwysCtdtVza7sgJOF8roklGWEs9SxIVFSjowFOcxteEqxZ8mRrZufw)

The algorithm tries also to "save" on space by iteratively removing bits as it cycles through the primes. I feel that the decimal to bit conversion could probably be shorter, but I could not figure out other alternatives.

Saved 6 bytes thanks to Jonathan French.

Comment: I think R supports chained assignment; `p=j=2` is two bytes shorter than `p=2;j=2`.

Comment: ...which can probably also be done for `a=p`, saving yet another two bytes.

Comment: ...and -- I do not know why -- it also seems to work for `y=1`, replaced with `y=2`, resulting in [200 bytes](https://tio.run/##HY/BboMwEETv/gqKFGW3WSqcVBwQ7qHf0BvlYFxQTRJjgWlxEN9OTa@jmac3w9aKrZ2Mcro3YHCRwopOeHFmbT@AjrSJzrlJOC6/3/rWwDjdwWPx@ixxmYUcX776qQ750PyANu6jf9duhA4RmRcKPM2lmu77asa3tELWie7EV1YLnstQ8WVSV@wh@sk1A1yLpD5JsnQ8HI7IbCDIIrmWT9Lam4dHwYlTgGFV8oosruzfpwysCtdtVza7sgJOF8roklGWEs9SxIVFSjowFOcxteEqxZ8mRrZufw).

Comment: Thank you. The y=2 replaces the bit for numeral 1. It works because for n>1, it is pruned away at the first iteration, and for n=1, the for loop loops backward, thus providing the answer for n=3, which is still 2 (not that bad of a luck).

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
RBFṁ
RÆNSÇṫÆNC$S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/Iye3hzkauoMNtfsGH2x/uXA1kOKsE/z/c/qhpzf//hgYA)

### Explanation

```
RBFṁ  Helper link. Input: integer k
R     Range, [1, 2, ..., k]
 B    Convert each to a list of its binary digits
  F   Flatten
   ṁ  Shape it to length k

RÆNSÇṫÆNC$S  Main link. Input: integer n
R            Range, [1, 2, ..., n]
 ÆN          Get i'th prime for each
   S         Sum
    Ç        Call helper link
         $   Monadic chain
      ÆN       Get n'th prime
        C      Complement, 1 - n'th prime
     ṫ       Tail, take the last n'th prime digits
          S  Sum
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 144 bytes

```js
n=>eval("s=o=j=0;for(i=p=1;n;d>p&&(n--,s+=p))for(p++,d=2;p%d++;);while(b=Math.log2(++j)+1|0,i<=s)for(x=0;x++<b&i<=s;)o+=i++>s-p&&j<<x&1<<b?1:0")
```

### Ungolfed

```js
n=>{
    s=o=j=0;
    for(i=p=1;n;d>p&&(n--,s+=p))
        for(p++,d=2;p%d++;);
    while(b=Math.log2(++j)+1|0,i<=s)
        for(x=0;x++<b&i<=s;)
            o+=i++>s-p&&j<<x&1<<b?1:0
    return o
}
```

### Test Cases

```js
f=
n=>eval("s=o=j=0;for(i=p=1;n;d>p&&(n--,s+=p))for(p++,d=2;p%d++;);while(b=Math.log2(++j)+1|0,i<=s)for(x=0;x++<b&i<=s;)o+=i++>s-p&&j<<x&1<<b?1:0")

;[1,3,6,36,60,160,260,350].forEach(t=>console.log(t,"->",f(t)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 67 bytes

```perl6
{(1..*).map(|*.base(2).comb).rotor(grep *.is-prime,2..*)[$_-1].sum}
```

[Test it](https://tio.run/##TU7BSsQwFLznKx5LkaQ26Sa1tUtp8LoXT95ckW4bpbBpQpKCsu6XefPHaru7oJdh3sy8Yaxyh2LSn3DTmk5BPR0xZywmTDcWf8Vs33iFBWGt0XvCnAnG4XenLMSs99S6XqtELA/P0SvlL8yP@jSNXsGT8qFCc/FDmBnUEMXbx3MNTnfdbUp@vtl2mCP20AzXUAqiQm/GXU8qIeoHO4YEIvVhVRtUB0cE0HtY1uKLS/7ZCawuItTyT11V6DRxKgXKFiioLFE2432JijWVvMgRX0heciTOynqzQVm@sOwu/wU)

### Expanded:

```perl6
{  # bare block lambda with implicit parameter ｢$_｣

  (

    1 .. *                # Range of all numbers starting with 1

  ).map(

    # WhateverCode lambda
    |                     # Slip each of these values into the outer list individually
      *                   # this is the parameter
      .base(2)            # convert base
      .comb               # split into digits


  ).rotor(                # split into chunks

    grep *.is-prime, 2..* # the sequence of prime numbers


  )[ $_ - 1]              # index into it using 1 based indexing

  .sum                    # find the sum
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>138</s> <s>132</s> 123 bytes

```js
N=>(n=k=1,g=s=>N?g((P=n=>n%--x?P(n):x<2)(x=++n)?s[n]?s.slice(--N&&n,n/!N):s+(n--,k++).toString(2):s):s.split`1`.length-1)``
```

#### Test cases

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc3faoMwGAXw@z2Fu1hJiJ8mdto/LPoGUtjlKNO61GaGL6UJQ/bymZR5MWFwrs6Pw/lsv1rX3fTVw6k9KQNoP1Q4RzLUsiQoByniXjpZ1lVPyEGiLPEJYKwOBOl@fMkoGSVjSCv3hsfKJc7oThGAerXCGNPHmu4dIwgQD4zRxNtXf9PYk2zqpyTuarRvRJMYhb2/gKBNEzqLzhqVGNuTMxGURlGUplH28BfW/0Exw3a5uMsEm6UU/FdEkS9I3G2ifCsWlM0k@G63/MpnWz/nIQA433bDu9PfSmac8x8)

#### Demo

*NB: Only 'safe' test cases are included here (guaranteed to work on Chrome, Firefox and Edge). You may have to increase the call stack size of your engine to pass the other ones.*

```js
let f =

N=>(n=k=1,g=s=>N?g((P=n=>n%--x?P(n):x<2)(x=++n)?s[n]?s.slice(--N&&n,n/!N):s+(n--,k++).toString(2):s):s.split`1`.length-1)``

console.log(f(1))   // 2
console.log(f(3))   // 2
console.log(f(6))   // 8
console.log(f(36))  // 78
console.log(f(60))  // 165
```

#### Formatted and commented

```js
N => (                            // given N = index of the expected term
  n = k = 1,                      // n = current prime, k = current natural number
  g = s =>                        // g = recursive function taking s = binary string
    N ?                           //   if we haven't reached the correct chunk yet:
      g(                          //     do a recursive call to g():
        (P = n =>                 //       P() returns: true for prime
          n % --x ? P(n) : x < 2) //                    false for composite
        (x = ++n) ?               //       increment n; if n is prime:
          s[n] ?                  //         if s is long enough:
            s.slice(--N && n,     //           either remove this chunk (if N > 0)
                    n / !N)       //           or truncate it to the correct size (if N = 0)
          :                       //         else:
            s + (n--, k++)        //           append the next natural number to s
                .toString(2)      //           in binary format
        :                         //       else:
          s                       //         just look for the next prime
      )                           //     end of recursive call
    :                             //   else:
      s.split`1`.length - 1       //     return the number of 1's in the last chunk
)``                               // initial call to g() with an empty string
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 114 bytes

```python
n=input();k=m=1;p=[0];s=''
exec's+=bin(k)[2:];p+=m%k*[k+p[-1]];m*=k*k;k+=1;'*n*n*2
print s[p[n-1]:p[n]].count('1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY9JDoMwDEXX5BTeVGYIFaESCyL3IlEWTFVRiokYpPb0NLT6sv/Gw/v@sz1nLo9u7gcgQMSDaWS/b3GiHU2ktCdTWL0SohjeQ4drRu3IsUtMWVvtM5ouLjUu8yZX1uopJZc67bKwiikHlcIvI2@wGm84zNTBrL12885bjAqTI7wV4jEvwDAyKAk3CVXooapCgqqKWkT/IywB8ztKEf0oA/Ormdq@qYFFdPLBGeX4Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>143</s> <s>139</s> 133 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to @ErikTheOutgolfer*

```python
s='1';i=x=1
exec"s=s[i:];i+=1\nwhile~-all(i%x for x in range(2,i)):i+=1\nexec's+=bin(x)[2:];x+=1;'*i;"*input()
print s[:i].count('1')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7dDoIgHMXveQrW1gCtJrhck/Ek5oUZ5X9z4AAX3fTqhHVxrs7H7yzvMFkj0mjvWjlCSPKKcCJBRcWRjnrceeU7aHsJpeJX85pg1p/jMM8U9hE/rMMRg8FuME9NxQEYa//JrUx8qW5gaGSdyBMxG5IUIHcFmGUNlKHFgQnYdy30p9GuJtCMZyk/@dHxdqy4JI5q1KC6QU2FeJbIqs/VFw)

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYtBCsMgEADveYUEipqk0EhPkX2JzcEW2ywkG4mG2Eu/bi29DcyMf8dpJZVzAM41Qq8TXCqX3KPGFvobHRPO7nO28yzwlNhz3VhiSGyz9HJCdSjl8C9/E08FdWjhjiSSNGoYNW9QWwj7IhbrBVLsghlwlFIHCAZLUTdIfo9CVn4rntmcr18) by removing incompatible test harness. [Another -2](https://tio.run/##JctBDsIgEEDRfU9BmhigrYsSVyVzEuwCDdpJ2ikBGnHj1RHj@r/v32nZSZUSgXONkGFsXHb3FnsYr/RacHWfs11XgafMHntgmSGxYOnphBpQyukvfxOPPdyQRJZGTbPONWjeobYQj01s1gukNEQz4SyljhANVtZ2SP5IQjY@1M5sKZcv) by rearranging some stuff.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer thanks a lot. I was still able to add my old tests back.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 48 bytes

```
([:+/-@{:{.+/{.[:}:[:(#:@[,])/1+[:i.1++/)@:p:@i.
```

### explained

```
(                                                         )@:p:@i.  the first n primes, passed to...
       -@{: {.                    ...                               take "nth prime" elements from the tail of...
               +/                                                   sum the first n primes and...
                  {.                                                take that number of elements from...
                     [: }:                                          all but the last element of...   <----------------<
                                          1 + [: i. 1 + +/          sum first n primes, add 1 (so we have enough      |
                                                                    for case n=1) -- make that many natural numbers   |
                           [: (#:@[ , ])/                           reduce them by turning into lists of binary       |
                                                                    digits and catting, however the rightmost number  |
                                                                    won't get reduced, hence the need for ------------^
([: +/                                                              and sum those digits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcNBCsMgEAXQvaf4pIsok47a5YeA9xi6KpGYTQpZSs5u@@Ado15YiYT/4Y0Sn6Wzq8SuxptG/2Cx5R1iFmPTLBJD4Zel6QhuUsx15YwFN1Ev57bPfsLXKQVkCJq@0vgB)

Comment: 30 bytes using key (`/.`): `_1({]+//.$$&;<@#:@#\)[:#~p:@i.`

Comment: super clever.  thanks miles.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 1+ + substr, 135 bytes

```
for(n=prompt(s=P=0),i=n*n*n*8;--i;)s=i.toString(2)+s;for(p=1;n;e=j?s:--n?P+=p:s.substr(P,p))for(j=p++;p%j--;);eval([].join.call(e,'+'))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "4?" are you unsure of the version? Expanding on what you mean in the body would help make this post better.

Comment: I know it runs when JS5 didn't come, but not that sure exactly when